# Extract multiple xml attributes to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I have a basic xml file called meals.xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meals name="Sample Text">
    <meal id="1" name="Poached Eggs" type="breakfast"/>
    <meal id="2" name="Club Sandwich" type="lunch"/>
    <meal id="3" name="Steak" type="dinner"/>
    <meal id="4" name="Steak" type="dinner"/>
</meals>
```

I want to extract both 'id' and 'name' attributes in to a dataframe. I can extract one when specifying one column and one attribute (eg, name only), but can't seem to figure out the syntax for getting multiple attributes in the for loop. This what I've tried, adding id to the 'df_cols' and 'attrib.get' function:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
root = ET.parse('meals.xml').getroot()

df_cols = ["id", "name"]
rows = []

for node in root:
    value = node.attrib.get('id', 'name')
    rows.append(value)
 
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)   
df
```

Can someone advise how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below may work for you

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meals name="Sample Text">
    <meal id="1" name="Poached Eggs" type="breakfast"/>
    <meal id="2" name="Club Sandwich" type="lunch"/>
    <meal id="3" name="Steak" type="dinner"/>
    <meal id="4" name="Steak" type="dinner"/>
</meals>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [{'id': m.attrib['id'], 'name': m.attrib['name']} for m in root.findall('.//meal')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  id           name
0  1   Poached Eggs
1  2  Club Sandwich
2  3          Steak
3  4          Steak
```

Comment: that seems to work fine. What about in my example when just supplying the xml file locally, not included in the code? `root = ET.parse('meals.xml').getroot()` returns an empty dataframe and I get an error when passing the file path to xml variable and using 'fromstring(xml)'

Comment: replace `root = ET.fromstring(xml)` with `root = ET.parse('meals.xml')`

Comment: Additionally, do not leave attributes out. I.e. if only ID and Type were required and not Name, do ID, Name and Type in the line that populates the Data variable, else it will produce an error